# How do I use Hiera to construct a config file using file's 'content' attribute?

Tags: puppet, hiera

- I'm looking for a generic solution so sysctl.conf is just an example.

I have several lines of configuration I need to be sure exist in all my servers' sysctl.conf:

```
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables = 0
kernel.msgmnb = 65536
kernel.msgmax = 65536
kernel.shmmax = 1519344680
kernel.shmall = 4294967296
net.core.rmem_max = 33554432
net.core.wmem_max = 33554432
net.core.rmem_default = 33554432
net.core.wmem_default = 33554432
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 131072 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 131072 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_sack = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_fack = 1
```

The sysctl.conf file expects no leading blank spaces in the file.
I'd like to stuff all the above lines into a yaml file so as to comply with Craig Dunn's Roles/Profiles methodology.

If I try to use this format:

```
`content: "kernel.msgmnb = 65536\n kernel.msgmax = 65536\n kernel.shmmax = 1519344680\n kernel.shmall = 4294967296\n net.core.rmem_max = 33554432\n net.core.wmem_max = 33554432\n net.core.rmem_default = 33554432\n net.core.wmem_default = 33554432\n"`
```

the resultant file is written with a whitespace character in column 0 for each line but the first. I need a newline but I don't want the leading whitespace.

I'm trying to nail down a simple, easily replicable way to reproduce a config file on all my nodes WITHOUT using template erb files. I want all my lines of config in a yaml file.

Here is my module's init.pp:

```
class sysctl_conf   {
  $sysctl_lines = hiera('sysctl_conf')
    file { '/tmp/test.txt':
    content => $sysctl_lines,
    }
}
```

If in common.yaml I use:

sysctl_conf:
    'content' :   "net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0\n net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1\n net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route = 0 kernel.sysrq = 0 kernel.core_uses_pid = 1 net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1 net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 0 net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 0 net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables = 0 kernel.msgmnb = 65536\n kernel.msgmax = 65536\n"
I end up with " Munging failed for value in class content: can't convert Hash into String"

Comment: If in common.yaml I use:

sysctl_conf:
    'content' :   "net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0\n net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1\n net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route = 0 kernel.sysrq = 0 kernel.core_uses_pid = 1 net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1 net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 0 net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 0 net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables = 0 kernel.msgmnb = 65536\n kernel.msgmax = 65536\n kernel.shmmax = 1519344680\n kernel.shmall = 4294967296\n net.core.rmem_max = 33554432\n net.core.wmem_max = 33554432\n net.core.rmem_default = 33554432\n"

Answer (score 3):

There are different ways to go about this.

Personally I think keeping the whole file as one string in your YAML is a poor choice, but the [syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML#Syntax) for that would be

```
sysctl_content: |
      net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1
      net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 0
      ...
```

A better alternative is an array

```
sysctl_lines:
  - net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies=1
  - net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables=0
```

Then get them into the file using a template such as

```
# This file is managed by Puppet
<% scope.function_hiera("sysctl_lines", []).each do |line| -%>
<%= line %>
<% end -%>
```

Or better yet, make it a hash

```
sysctl_settings:
  net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies: 1
  net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables: 0
  ...
```

And a template like

```
# This file is managed by Puppet
<% scope.function_hiera("sysctl_settings", []).each do |key,val| -%>
<%= key %> = <%= val %>
<% end -%>
```

This has the advantage that you can spread distinct value overrides throughout your hierarchy if you use the `hiera_hash` lookup method instead.

Comment: Now the logic in my init.pp is all broken:

Comment: So, what did you change? What broke?

Comment: class sysctl_conf   {
    $sysctl_lines = hiera_hash('sysctl_conf')
    file { '/tmp/test.txt':
    content => template("settings.erb"),
    }
}

Comment: Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass at /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/manifests/site.pp:34 on node vmtest2.lvs01.ederp.com
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run

Comment: Do I need to use create_resources for this one?

Comment: No. The `template("settings.erb")` looks fishy to me. Your template should be in a module and use the appropriate path, e.g. `sysctl/settings.erb`, see http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/templating.html#using-templates

Answer (score 1):

Managing sysctl conf with templates and files is an awful idea.

There are dozens of applications that might need to make alterations, so you don't want 1 module to control them all.

This is a much better way to do it : [link](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/1/wiki/puppet_augeas#etcsysctlconf)

Now you can set individual settings in individual modules, or have your base class have certain settings, and have you database class (for example) configure other settings without having to redefine the entire file.

Comment: I don't understand how Augeas fits in to roles/profiles.

Comment: And I think when you speak of template files you mean storing data in template files is bad. I tend to agree.

Answer (score 1):

Although your approach may not be the best idea and the other answers show better approaches:

Your white space in front of each line but the first is there, because you put it there:

```
content: "kernel.msgmnb = 65536\n kernel.msgmax = 65536\n kernel.shmmax = 1519344680\n kernel.shmall = 4294967296\n net.core.rmem_max = 33554432\n net.core.wmem_max = 33554432\n net.core.rmem_default = 33554432\n net.core.wmem_default = 33554432\n"
```

You've put a `" "` after each and every `"\n"`. That's the problem.
Replace each `"\n "` with `"\n"` any you are fine.